# Update and get the data in the same ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to update and get the updated row at a time from database in ajax call

JS in ready function

```
$("button[name='teacher_lock_exam']").on(ace.click_event, function () {
    var current_exams_id = $(this).attr('id');

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to lock the exam? <br/><br/>" +
        "Locked exam cannot be modified until exam committee unlock it.", function (result) {
        if (result) {

            lock_exam(current_exams_id);
            bootbox.alert("Your Exam has been Locked !<br/><br/> Contact with Exam committee to modify that exam again.");
        }
    });

});
function lock_exam(current_exams_id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "teacher_internal_exam_management/lock_exam/" + current_exams_id,
        type: "POST",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (row) {
            alert('success');
            alert(row[0].access_status);


        }

    });


}
```

My teacher_internal_exam_management controller

```
public function lock_exam($current_exams_id)
{

    $this->load->model('teacher_internal_exam_management_model');
    $this->teacher_internal_exam_management_model->lock_exam($current_exams_id);

    echo (json_encode($this->teacher_internal_exam_management_model->get_exam_details($current_exams_id)));

}
```

My teacher_internal_exam_management_model Model

```
function lock_exam($current_exam_id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->query("update current_exams set access_status = 'locked' where current_exams_id='".$current_exam_id."'");

    }
function get_exam_details($exam_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from  current_exams
                                where
                                    current_exams_id = '" . $exam_id . "'

                            ");

        return $query->result();
    }
```

Now the ajax call is updating the data but the row is not returned by the echo in the controller.Means the success function of ajax is not running. Why this is not working? Is there any problem in the code?

Comment: is your URL is right relatively.

Comment: yes... i have checked it at the first time and re checked just now.. yes

Comment: Does it gives error in Chrome Network tab Or Console tab. In my opinion it URL issue. Where is your Js located.

Comment: js is loading just fine. Console Tab is not giving any error report too.

Comment: As a side note, you should pass `$exam_id` as a parameter instead of directly including it in the SQL query to prevent SQL injection. `$this->db->query("select * from current_exams where current_exams_id = ?", array($exam_id));`

Comment: thanks for the advice. But still i got stuck in that problem. It has been 2 days i am trying to get out of it. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very last line of your model:

`return $query->result();`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

```
This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.
```

This is returning an **array of objects**.

You have to convert it appropriately -

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I just tried it. Sorry no luck. Still not showing that alert() on success in ajax

Comment: Your Model's `lock_exam` expects 2 parameters but you are only passing one in. Either remove the `$data` param (since you don't seem to be using it), or pass in something.

Comment: Thanks Just worked when i removed the $data parameter. I didn't see that coming. Great you are my hero.....

Answer (score -2):

According to the php manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php, I do not see a result() method for the type mysqli_result. I think you need to use

```
return $query->fetch_all();
```

instead of

```
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I am using mysql not mysqli. So 
    return 
    $query->fetch_all(); 
is not working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP's mysqli functions, he is using Codeigniter's ActiveRecord

Comment: wondering if @user2557992 even knows difference between mysql and mysqli